# WindowChrome Negative ResizeBorderThickness (resize from outside)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to simulate the behavior of ResizeBorderThickness but allow the user to resize the window when they're 6 pixels outside of the window instead of inside. This is how VisualStudio's resize works and I prefer it over the default resize funcionality (which would be 6 pixels inside of the window).

I tried using a negative thickness but as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome.resizeborderthickness.aspx) it's not allowed. Would the only option be to have a 6 pixel invisible border around the window, that way it would seem like you were outside of the window?

**I want this:**

[image: Want this]

Comment: I always thought that was the result of making a borderless window with a transparent background, with an opaque content element that's smaller (5 pixel all around) so that the content element can cast it's shadow/blur over the larger transparent window. The resize arrow then rests where it naturally would be, at the edge of the transparent window.

Comment: @Vlad I was thinking I might have to do something like that. Thanks for your input!