# Maximize Window with Transparent Border

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm trying to maximize a window which has a transparent border. When maximized, the transparent border shouldn't show. I follow the method found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/maximizing-window-_2800_with-windowstyle_3d00_none_2900_-considering-taskbar.aspx) and by using the below code I can get it to work half way.

```
void win_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.IntPtr handle = (new WinInterop.WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
    WinInterop.HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new WinInterop.HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
}

private static System.IntPtr WindowProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg,
          System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
    switch (msg) {
        case 0x0024:/* WM_GETMINMAXINFO */
            WmGetMinMaxInfo(hwnd, lParam);
            handled = true;
            break;
    }
    return (System.IntPtr)0;
}

private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr lParam) {     
    MINMAXINFO mmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

    // Adjust the maximized size and position to fit the work area of the correct monitor
    int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST =0x00000002;
    System.IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

    if (monitor != System.IntPtr.Zero) {
        MONITORINFO monitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
        GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
        RECT rcWorkArea = monitorInfo.rcWork;
        RECT rcMonitorArea = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
        mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.left - rcMonitorArea.left) - thickness;
        mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.top - rcMonitorArea.top) - thickness;
        mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.right - rcWorkArea.left) + 2 * thickness; 
        mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.bottom - rcWorkArea.top) + 2 * thickness;
    }

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, lParam, true);
}
```

The screenshot below shows how it's expanded correctly in the horizontal direction but for some reason it won't stretch in the vertical direction.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show complete code that called this

Comment: @lll I've added more code. I followed the code found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/maximizing-window-_2800_with-windowstyle_3d00_none_2900_-considering-taskbar.aspx) except for the thickness offset.

Comment: Where is Thickness defined?

Comment: In the Xaml. It's an integer (100). @lll

Comment: Is this Window always maximized? Or can be not maximized

Comment: Well I'll be using it in a project where it can be not maximized. The code I've attached is always maximized. @lll

Comment: It doesn't work because the Window class also installs a hook to process WM_GETMINMAXINFO and it gets to it long before you do.  I doubt you can get ahead of it, you can't override its CreateHwndSourceParameters() method and there's too much icky internal state associated with it.

Comment: So you want the window to be **always maximized** without the transparent border, correct?

Comment: @lll I don't want it always maximized. I want the window to behave as if it doesn't have a transparent border. The border will be 6 pixels that way I can resize the window from the outside of the window. This question explains what I'm trying to achieve. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943321/windowchrome-negative-resizeborderthickness-resize-from-outside)

Comment: @HansPassant Then how would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943321/windowchrome-negative-resizeborderthickness-resize-from-outside) be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant Also, why would it work horizontally but not vertically?

Comment: It doesn't, not on my machine for example.  The maximized size is rather random.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I'll have to modify the invisible border's thickness in the code behind to get my desired effect. @HansPassant

Comment: Seems like `MINMAXINFO.ptMaxTrackSize` limits windows maximal height. Try `mmi.ptMaxTrackSize = mmi.ptMaxSize;` after setting `ptMaxSize` in your `WmGetMinMaxInfo`. This will allow window to expand to full height.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work :( @sasha_gud Thanks anyways!

Comment: It' probably caused by fact that I have to monitors at the moment. Therefore it works on my pc.

Comment: I've checked with a single monitor and it still works somehow. Can someone try this too? I'll post updated code as an answer to move discussion there if any.

Comment: It works in the sample project! I was trying it in the project where it will be used and it doesn't work for some reason. Thanks so much! @sasha_gud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following code with updating `MINMAXINFO.ptMaxTrackSize` and it works.
Related problem is also described here: [Can a window be resized past the screen size/offscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123410/can-a-window-be-resized-past-the-screen-size-offscreen)

```
private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr lParam) {     
    MINMAXINFO mmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

    // Adjust the maximized size and position to fit the work area of the correct monitor
    int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST =0x00000002;
    System.IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

    if (monitor != System.IntPtr.Zero) {
        MONITORINFO monitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
        GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
        RECT rcWorkArea = monitorInfo.rcWork;
        RECT rcMonitorArea = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
        mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.left - rcMonitorArea.left) - thickness;
        mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.top - rcMonitorArea.top) - thickness;
        mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.right - rcWorkArea.left) + 2 * thickness; 
        mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.bottom - rcWorkArea.top) + 2 * thickness;
        mmi.ptMaxTrackSize = mmi.ptMaxSize;
    }

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, lParam, true);
}
```